# Accessing a map using its reference

Tags: pointers, dictionary, go

I try to loop through a map, that I pass as a pointer to a function, but I can't find a way to access the elements. This is the code:

```
func refreshSession(sessions *map[string]Session) {
    now := time.Now()
    for sid := range *sessions {
        if now.After(*sessions[sid].timestamp.Add(sessionRefresh)) {
            delete( *sessions, sid )
        }
    }
}
```

Line 4 in this example return following compile error:

```
./controller.go:120: invalid operation: sessions[sid] (type *map[string]Session does not support indexing)
```

I tried brackets, but it had no effect. If I take away all reference operators (* &) then it compiles fine.

How must I write this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You don't need to use a pointer with a map.

> [Map types are reference types, like pointers or slices](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action)

If you needed to change the `Session` you could use a pointer:

`map[string]*Session`

Comment: question, would there be cases where its plausible to have a map's key to be pointer of x type?

Comment: Do you mean something like `map[*T]string`?

Comment: Is something like map[*T]string possible?

Comment: @harunrashid indeed, check out this example https://play.golang.com/p/GlEzMDDZdPa

Comment: map[string]*Session will not modify the map globally,  as original code does

Comment: @Savash yes it will, since a Map is a reference all changes to the map will be global. Here is a playground example to illustrate https://play.golang.org/p/Bmu-EAhreD5

Answer (score 18):

De-reference the map first and then access it ([Example on play](https://play.golang.org/p/PZ55WWpUj7R)):

```
(*sessions)[sid]
```

It's also noteworthy that maps are actually reference types and therefore there is a very limited use-case of using pointers. Just passing a map value to a function will not copy the content. [Example on play](http://play.golang.org/p/hpmbkNLuuh).

Answer (score 11):

You are not taking into account the precedence of `*`.

`*session[sid]` really means `*(session[sid])`, that is, first indexing the pointer to map (hence the error), then dereferencing it.

You should use `(*session)[sid].timestamp` to first dereference the pointer to the map and then access it using the key.

Comment: I find this very rare. I tried it and it works: http://play.golang.org/p/85Mj8RixGm . If @jmaloney solutions works for you, are you sure you are using the same code you posted here?

Comment: I had other issues in the code. So it changed. I updated it in the question above. But the problem I had first went away after I got rid of all * and &.