# Are maps passed by value or by reference in Go?

Tags: go

Are maps passed by value or reference in Go ?

It is always possible to define a function as following, but is this an overkill ?

```
func foo(dat *map[string]interface{}) {...}
```

Same question for return value. Should I return a pointer to the map, or return the map as value ?

The intention is of course to avoid unnecessary data copy.

Comment: _Everything_ in Go is passed by value. Some values happen to be pointers, or structures that contain pointers. (you may want a `*map` in some cases, if you need to reassign the map value at an address)

Answer (score 150, accepted):

In this thread you will find your answer :

[Golang: Accessing a map using its reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384343/golang-accessing-a-map-using-its-reference)

> You don't need to use a pointer with a map.
>
> Map types are reference types, like pointers or slices[1]
>
> If you needed to change the Session you could use a pointer:
>
> ```
> map[string]*Session
> ```
>
> https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action

Comment: To avoid any pitfals, be aware that maps are only passed by reference once _initialized_, and when re-initialized inside a function, the original _reference_ will not be updated. Here is a illustrative playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/Q6vrAmmJWR6

Or a full article by Dave Cheny https://dave.cheney.net/2017/04/29/there-is-no-pass-by-reference-in-go

Comment: Wrong - maps always get passed the same regardless of whether nil or not. Also a map cannot be reinitialized without passing a pointer to it and using a dereferencing assignment. The same linked code proves the latter and the former is easily proven by not initializing the map. Go is easy to get wrong as the 19 upvotes show.

Comment: Personally I think it is misleading to mention (in passing) that "slices are reference types", as they're not really are they? If you pass a slice by value to a function and then append to it multiple times, the caller's copy of that slice is not guaranteed to be updated - instead the called function needs to pass back a new value of the slice. This is because if the slice re-allocates, you get a new _value_ for the slice (hence `a = append(a, v)` rather than just `append(a, v)`)

Maps do not have this semantic, once a map is created it can be updated without ever yielding a new map value.

Answer (score 53):

Here are some parts from [If a map isn’t a reference variable, what is it?](https://dave.cheney.net/2017/04/30/if-a-map-isnt-a-reference-variable-what-is-it) by Dave Cheney:

> A map value is a pointer to a `runtime.hmap` structure.

and conclusion:

> **Conclusion**
>
> Maps, like channels, but unlike slices, are just pointers to runtime
> types. As you saw above, a map is just a pointer to a `runtime.hmap`
> structure.
>
> Maps have the same pointer semantics as any other pointer value in a
> Go program. There is no magic save the rewriting of map syntax by the
> compiler into calls to functions in `runtime/hmap.go`.

And an interesting bit about history/explanation of `map` syntax:

> **If maps are pointers, shouldn’t they be `*map[key]value`?**
>
> It’s a good question that if maps are pointer values, why does the
> expression `make(map[int]int)` return a value with the type
> `map[int]int`. Shouldn’t it return a `*map[int]int`? Ian Taylor
> [answered this recently in a golang-nuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/SjuhSYDITm4/jnrp7rRxDQAJ) thread<sup>1</sup>.
>
> > In the very early days what we call maps now were written as pointers,
> > so you wrote `*map[int]int`. We moved away from that when we realized
> > that no one ever wrote `map` without writing `*map`.
>
> Arguably renaming the type from `*map[int]int` to `map[int]int`, while
> confusing because the type does not look like a pointer, was less
> confusing than a pointer shaped value which cannot be dereferenced.

Answer (score 16):

No. Maps are reference by default.

```
    package main

    import "fmt"

    func mapToAnotherFunction(m map[string]int) {
        m["hello"] = 3
        m["world"] = 4
        m["new_word"] = 5
    }

    // func mapToAnotherFunctionAsRef(m *map[string]int) {
    // m["hello"] = 30
    // m["world"] = 40
    // m["2ndFunction"] = 5
    // }

    func main() {
        m := make(map[string]int)
        m["hello"] = 1
        m["world"] = 2

        // Initial State
        for key, val := range m {
            fmt.Println(key, "=>", val)
        }

        fmt.Println("-----------------------")

        mapToAnotherFunction(m)
        // After Passing to the function as a pointer
        for key, val := range m {
            fmt.Println(key, "=>", val)
        }

        // Try Un Commenting This Line
        fmt.Println("-----------------------")

        // mapToAnotherFunctionAsRef(&m)
        // // After Passing to the function as a pointer
        // for key, val := range m {
        //  fmt.Println(key, "=>", val)
        // }

        // Outputs
        // hello => 1
        // world => 2
        // -----------------------
        // hello => 3
        // world => 4
        // new_word => 5
        // -----------------------

    }
```

From Golang Blog-

> Map types are reference types, like pointers or slices, and so the value of m above is nil; it doesn't point to an initialized map. A nil map behaves like an empty map when reading, but attempts to write to a nil map will cause a runtime panic; don't do that. To initialize a map, use the built in make function:

```
// Ex of make function
m = make(map[string]int)
```

[Code Snippet Link](https://play.golang.org/p/szbqYdt3YLR) Play with it.

Comment: They are not reference types (though they are indirect types). If you assign to a map value, you will break its relationship with other variables. Go has no reference types, everything is a value.  You can demonstrate this with `func mapToAnotherFunction(m map[string]int) { m = nil }`, it doesn't empty the map, just overwrites its value in a local way.

Comment: Isn't your first comment `// After Passing to the function as a pointer` incorrect?

Comment: @Wug Quoting [a post from the official go blog](https://go.dev/blog/maps), "Map types are reference types, like pointers or slices"

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/6ILv9oZNAvG